# Comparing Vector Values

Tags: r, vector, random

`I'm wondering how I would go about altering this code so that corresponding values of both vectors cannot be equal. As an example: if x = (1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 1, 7, 9, 5, 10) and y = (3, 2, 7, 8, 4, 10, 4, 8, 2, 1), the second values for both vectors equal 2.  Is there any way I can tell R to re-sample in this second spot in vector x until it is not the same value in vector y?

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(1:10)
sample_x <- sample(x, length(10), replace = TRUE)
z <- sample_x > y`
```

Comment: `length(10)` is `1`, something odd with your code. Also `sample_x > y` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `sample_x` in the OP code is of size 1, so `sample_x > y` will check `sample_x` against every value in `y`.  (I'm sure not what was intended, but will run just fine)

Comment: I was thinking length(10) would create a vector of length 10, but I guess not. I was trying to sample 10 times from x while replacing the values. Thus, z would give me TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the value in sample_x is larger than its corresponding value in vector y.

Comment: side note: to get a vector of length `n` integers use `seq(n)`

Comment: So you meant `sample_x <- sample(x, 10, replace = TRUE)` and maybe `z <- sample_x == y` or `z <- any(sample_x == y)`.

Answer (score 7):

You could do:

```
while(any(x == y)) x <- sample(x)
```

---

**Edit**: Now I realize `x` and `y` probably come from a similar `sample` call with `replace = TRUE`, here is an interesting approach that avoids a `while` loop. It uses indices and modulo to ensure that the two samples do not match:

```
N <- 1:10  # vector to choose from (assumes distinct values)
L <- 20    # sample size - this might be length(N) as in your example

n <- length(N)

i <- sample(n,   L, replace = TRUE)
j <- sample(n-1, L, replace = TRUE)

x <- N[i]
y <- N[1 + (i + j - 1) %% n]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
while (any(ind <- x==y))
   x[ind] <- sample(N, sum(ind), TRUE)
```

*where `N` is what you are sampling from (or the max integer)*

The advantage here is that if you do not need to resample all of `x`, then this will converge more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function permn from library combinat to generate all permutations of vector of length 10.

```
ind <- permn(10)
xy_any_equal <- sapply(ind, function(i) any(x[i] == y))
if(sum(xy_any_equal) < length(xy_any_equal)) x_perm <- x[head(ind[!xy_any_equal],1)[[1]]]
exists(x_perm)
```

Comment: seriously? would you recommend that over the two solutions already posted?

Comment: I would not recommend it when vector is longer than 7.